# Let f : X → Y be injective. Define the function g : X → f(X) by g(x) = f(x). Prove that g is invertible.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : X → Y be injective. Define the function g : X → f(X) by g(x) = f(x). Prove that
g is invertible.

For a function g to be invertible, we must show its injective and surjective.

---

Let x,y be elements of X.

Then g(x) = g(y)

Then by definition f(x)= f(y)

And because f is injective  x=y

so g is injective

---

I'm having trouble showing that it is surjective.

Let f(a) be an element of f(X).

Then there exists an element a of X

such that g(a) = f(a)

How would I solve for a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f:X \rightarrow Y$ is Injective.

$g: X \rightarrow f(X) \subset Y$ ; $g(x)=f($);

1)  $f$ Injective implies $g$ Injective (already proven).

2)  $g$ is surjective.

Let $b \in f(X)$, then $b=f(x)$ for some $x \in X$.

For this $x$ : $g(x)=f(x)=b$, done.

We have shown that for $b \in f(X)$, there is a $x \in X$, s.t.

$g(x)=b$, hence surjective.

Note :

The range of $g$ is the image of $f$ $(f(X))$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ What will be the image of $g$?

First observe that $g(X) \subseteq f(X).$ Now let $y \in f(X).$ Then $\exists$ $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y.$ Since $g(x)= f(x),$ for all $x \in X$ we have that $g(x) = y.$ So $y \in g(X).$ Therefore $g(X) \supseteq f(X).$  This shows that $g(X)= f(X)$ and hence $g$ is onto or surjective.